# Is there a better way to structure this SQL Query?

Tags: sql, query-optimization

I have devised an answer to this problem (which I’ll post at the end) but I’m just wondering if there is a ‘cleaner’ way to structure the query.

The question is as follows:

What is the title and year published of the newest Philip Roth book? You cannot use the ORDER BY clause. Write a single SQL statement. Use Sub-queries. Do not assume that you already know the AuthorId for Philip Roth, the BookId for his latest book or the year the latest book was released.

The relevant tables from the Database:

```
Books (BookId, Title, YearPublished)
Authors (AuthorId, FirstName, LastName)
WrittenBy  (AuthorId, BookId)
```

My solution:

```
SELECT Title, YearPublished
FROM Books NATURAL JOIN Authors NATURAL JOIN WrittenBy
WHERE YearPublished = (SELECT MAX(YearPublished)
                       FROM Books NATURAL JOIN Authors NATURAL JOIN WrittenBy
                       WHERE AuthorId = (SELECT AuthorId
                                         FROM Authors
                                         WHERE FirstName = 'Philip'
                                         AND LastName = 'Roth'))
AND FirstName = 'Philip'
AND LastName = 'Roth';
```

I can’t figure out a way to not specify the First and Last names again. Otherwise it just lists all the books published in the same year as Philip Roth’s latest publication.

This query works perfectly. But, is there a cleaner way to query this?

Thanks :)

(as for which DBMS I am using: These are some review exercises for an exam. We have to use one created and supplied by the university. It’s very basic SQL. Simpler than Access 2010)

Comment: What is the DBMS? Can you use `first_value()` function? by the way that needs `ORDER BY`, so ignore my question.

Comment: @AmirPashazadeh Hi! DBMS is one created by our lecturer. available only to us students. we have not learned about first_value() yet so I would say that no I can't.

Comment: I have two comments:
(a) you dont need Authors in the outer subquery, as you're not using it there, & 
(b) I'd suggest aliasing table names and adding aliases to column names for clarity

Comment: @JohnBingham ahh yes. good point. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have that simpler with a `NOT EXISTS` anti-semi-join:

```
SELECT b.Title, b.YearPublished
FROM   Authors         AS a
NATURAL JOIN WrittenBy AS w
NATURAL JOIN Books     AS b
WHERE  a.FirstName = 'Philip'
AND    a.LastName = 'Roth'
NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   Books           AS b1
   NATURAL JOIN WrittenBy AS w1
   WHERE  w1.AuthorId = a.AuthorId
   AND    b1.YearPublished > b.YearPublished
   );
```

The question implies there is only a single book per year and author - or it would be ambiguous (you get multiple rows).

Comment: mmm yes. I didn't think about `NOT EXISTS`. good point. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

you can write the same as

```
SELECT Title, YearPublished
FROM Books NATURAL JOIN Authors NATURAL JOIN WrittenBy
WHERE YearPublished = (SELECT MAX(YearPublished)
                       FROM Books b NATURAL JOIN Authors a NATURAL JOIN WrittenBy wby
                       WHERE a.FirstName='Philip' and a.LastName='Roth')
AND FirstName = 'Philip'
AND LastName = 'Roth';
```

This solution remove the one subquery.